# Only Certain Embedded Fonts Work - Flex 4.6

Tags: flash, apache-flex, fonts, flash-builder, embed

I am at a complete loss now.....

I've been trying to embed this font into my Flex Mobile App:
        http://www.font-zone.com/download.php?fid=111

But it won't show up for some reason, it just reverts to the default....I've had the same problem with all custom fonts I've tried but one:
                               http://www.fonts101.com/fonts/view/Uncategorized/28299/Slider

Here is the code I am using:

```
global
{
    font-family: bank-gothic-medium-bt;
}
@font-face
{
    fontFamily: bank-gothic-medium-bt;
    src: url("D:\Users\Oisin\Pictures\MW3 Builder\bank-gothic-medium-bt.ttf");
    embedAsCFF: true;
}
```

I've tried multiple fonts, and fonts with single names (thought that might be the problem) but still nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have also had issues with certain fonts in Flex, I needed to change the fontManager which was being used, have a look and see if it helps - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e09.html

Comment: Tried playing around with the various fontManagers and cached fonts, but no luck unfortunately....
It seems like such a simple thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Got it....

For anyone else having this extremely ridiculous problem...

```
Ensure your font is BOLD!
```

Buttons by default use bold fonts, and even though I tried specifying the fontWeight(font-weight) to normal it wasn't working.

Now I can actually get started on the app.....phew!

Thanks for all your answers guys!

Answer (score 0):

This could be two things:

1. Flash does not embed every font. There are certain fonts it won't embed for legal reasons. However, I have never come across this issue outside of Flash CS. In Flash Builder, everything seems to work fine.
2. I believe you are setting fontFamily incorrectly. When you embed the font face, you need to pass a string value as the name. When you call it in the CSS, it should be without quotes. Here is how I embed fonts (using Flash Builder 4.5 and 4.6 with 3.1-3.4 AIR SDKs)

   @font-face 
   {
       src: url("assets/fonts/BebasNeue.otf");
       fontFamily: "BebasNeueEmbedded";
       embedAsCFF: true;
   }

   .progressMeterText 
    {
       fontFamily: BebasNeueEmbedded;
       fontLookup: embeddedCFF;
       color: #828282;
       fontSize: 18pt;
   }

I apologize if the formatting doesn't show up correctly. The editor doesn't seem to want to accept that formatting.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answering my question.
Unfortunately I have tried downloading Bebas Neue and using it in my app with the code you have provided.  Still nothing :/  I can change the color, size etc. but the font will only change to the one other specific font....no other ones. Could there be any other reason for this?
Using FB 4.6 & AiR 3.2

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) You're not importing your CSS file using `<fx:Style source="style.css"/>` or 2) global is not able to be used. I've never used global in Flex CSS, so I'm unsure if it is valid. Have you tried doing an individual setting of a label using `styleName="progressMeterText"`?

Comment: Style is definitely imported.  And I can change other properties no problem with the global attribute.
I tried using a custom style; it's working with labels but with nothing else (Except, again for Slider.ttf). How odd...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
var textLayoutFormat:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
textLayoutFormat.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;
textLayoutFormat.renderingMode = RenderingMode.CFF;

textLayoutFormat.color = 0x336633;
textLayoutFormat.fontFamily = "CUSTOM_FONT_FAMILY";
textLayoutFormat.fontSize = 14;

var uic:UIComponent = UIComponent(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication);
_textFlow.flowComposer.swfContext = ISWFContext(uic.getFontContext(textLayoutFormat.fontFamily, false, false, true));

IEditManager(_textFlow.interactionManager).applyFormatToElement(_textFlow,textLayoutFormat);
_textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
```

Particularly, below 2 lines are the solution:

```
var uic:UIComponent = UIComponent(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication);
_textFlow.flowComposer.swfContext = ISWFContext(uic.getFontContext(textLayoutFormat.fontFamily, false, false, true));
```

Comment: Oops sorry.. I was talking in Text Layout Framework context. As I was looking for a solution myself until a while back and looks like put it here instead of some other window :-|